# chemfig: chemical reaction label

Tags: equations, labels, chemfig

Can I set a label for a chemical reaction with chemfig, just like I can do with equation?

My MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation} \label{1}
    \Lambda = \dfrac{1}{R}
    \end{equation}

\begin{center}
    \schemestart
    \ce{CO^{$2-$}_3 ($aq$)} + \ce{H_{2}O ($l$)}
    \arrow{<=>}
    \ce{OH^{$-$} ($aq$)} \+ \ce{HCO^{$-$}_3 ($aq$)}
    \schemestop
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Result

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the `chemmacros` package and its `reactions` module:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=reactions}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation} \label{1}
    \Lambda = \dfrac{1}{R}
    \end{equation}

\begin{reaction}
    CO3^{2-} \aq{}  + H2O \lqd{}  <=>  OH- \aq{} + HCO3^{-}\aq{}
\end{reaction}

\end{document}
```